# c# PropertyInfo extract inner expression

Tags: c#, reflection, expression

I have to use reflection to cycle through some properties of a reflected object, and collect their `PropertyInfo` objects.

Some of those properties are of type `Expression<Func<Type1,string>>`, and I have to extract the underlying Expression from the property info.

I tried `myPropertyInfo.GetValue(parParameter) as LambdaExpression` but it does not seem to work.

Can anyone give me some pointers?

Comment: May be you can put `dynamic` to a good use here ?

Comment: Please show the code you have so far so it's easier to see where the problem occurs. Do you know the types `Type1` and `string` at compile time? I'm not sure, but I think an `Expression<Func<Type1,string>>` _is not a `LambdaExpresssion`_ in terms of types. What do you want to do with that value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your usage of `myPropertyInfo.GetValue(parParameter) as LambdaExpression` is suspect, because parameters and expressions are two different things.  It seems like you're mixing up your variables after you do the reflection.  Here's an example that may help to clarify things:

```
class Type1 { public string Name { get; set; } }
class Data { public Expression<Func<Type1, string>> Ex { get; set; } }
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var d = new Data { Ex = t => t.Name };
        var pi = d.GetType().GetProperties().Single();
        var ex = pi.GetValue(d) as LambdaExpression;
        Console.WriteLine(pi.GetValue(d).GetType());
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Parameters.Single());
    }
}
```